# Save vs Save As recommendation Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a `Tkinter` app and have a save function that using `cPickle`, saves the file. However, I am looking to do a save function(or an auto save) that does not pop-up the save dialog if the file has already been created. I am looking for recommendations on how to do this. I thought of checking to see if the function has been called before and if so, bypassing the dialog, but if the user cancels this process before the save than that would break this option I think. Should I be using `os.path.isfile` to see if the file exists perhaps?

```
def file_save_as(saved):
    """Save .gsd binary file"""
    designer_save_file = saved
    if not designer_save_file:
        designer_save_file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
            initialdir="C:/", mode="w",
            defaultextension=".db",
            filetypes=(("GSD", "*.gsd"), ("All files", "*"))
        )
        if designer_save_file is None:
            return
    else:

        gsd_save_name = designer_save_file.name
        basename = os.path.basename(gsd_save_name)
        path = os.path.dirname(gsd_save_name)

        gsd_data = {"Data"}
        
        pk.dump(gsd_data, open(path + "/" + basename, "wb"))
        full_path = path + "/" + basename
        return full_path


save_path = file_save_as(None)
file_save_as(save_path)
print(save_path)

# Hotkey to save current gsd portal progress
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+s", lambda: file_save_as(save_path))
```

Comment: You store a value somewhere to use as a flag. With a fresh unsaved file it will be `None`. This has to be set by the code after you save for the first time, and it can even be the filename you stored, instead of a separate flag.

Comment: If it is set, you bypass the dialog code and just save your data again.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response progmatico! Would this value be set within the function and then returned or outside the function?

Comment: Outside usually. You should establish a place where you store runtime data for your app, and so you store the filename there and read it from there. You can also pass it to the function call. If the function gets None it asks for a filename. Yes you can store by function side-effect or return it as (or as part of) function result.

Comment: Using `os.path.isfile()` would be a good approach. There's also `os.path.exists()`. You might want to use both to rule out some (obscure) possibilities.

Comment: Clearly I don't know what i am doing. So, the outside function call immediately brings up the filedialog and then when I run the app and passing the information as None works, but is not stored for another attempt when saving.

Comment: I don't know what you thought you were accomplishing with your last edit. Now your question is even more unclear. Why is there so much duplicated code (such as there now being two definitions of  the`file_save_as()` function)? What does the `keyboard` module have to do with things? It's very unlikely the ``keyboard` module is compatible with `tkinter` because they both will try to handle low-lever user input.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why when I edited the post, it added outside of the text box. I just removed the duplicate I think on the post (there is not duplicate in the code i should say). As for the keyboard shortcut, that is one of the ways I am calling the save function and so that is how I am testing.

Comment: A) Why do you call the function `file_save_as()` twice? (B) The result you're trying to achieve can be achieved by using `os.path.isfile()` or `os.path.exists()` to check if the file exists or not. If it does, continue to save to the same file; if it doesn't, create the file to save.

Comment: I guess this is where i am not sure what to do. If i use os.path.isfile(), I would have to call a global variable in the function as the path has not been created yet. If I create this as a separate function, I have to get the variable for the path outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all for your help. I ended up created a flag as mentioned and then passing in that path. Works perfectly.

```
def auto_save():
if os.path.isfile(file_flag):
    save_data(file_flag)
else:
    file_save_as()
```